# How can I find the optimal point that maximizes profit on a Demand Curve in R?

Tags: r, optimization, linear-regression, solver, price

Relatively new to R  so please bear with me - My dataset relates to one product. I have a list of Price points per unit which vary for this one product (price is dependent on salesperson decision), and a list of Quantities (number of units purchased at each price point), with the corresponding Profit for each transaction.

I have plotted a Demand Curve with Quantity on the Y axis and Unit Price on the X axis. I have also plotted a linear regression model which has given me the coefficient and intercept and allowed me to plot the abline showing the relationship. Code is as follows:

#Model

```
testlm <- lm(Dataset$Quantity Sold~Dataset$Unit Price)
```

#Plot

```
plot(Dataset$Unit Price, Dataset$Quantity Sold, 
     xlab = "Unit Price", ylab = "Quantity", pch=20, 
     ylim=c(0,40))
```

#abline

```
abline(a=11.38, b=-0.24, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

#Here is where I am trying to input two lines to cross an optimal point

```
abline(v=OptimalUnitPrice, lty=4, col = "red", lwd=2)
```

```
abline(h=OptimalQty, lty=4, col = "red", lwd=2)`
```

I am trying to figure out how to find the values for OptimalUnitPrice and OptimalQty - I am trying to find a function that works similarly to Excel's Solver - which allows me to find the optimal Price that factor's in the Quantity and maximizes the Profit. I believe I would have to overlay profit into the relationship and/or graph somehow but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Could someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It would help us a lot if you can provide sample data.  Can you please add some sample data or reference a dataset that ships with R?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example can help you.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

# linear function 
linear <- function(p, alpha, beta) {
  alpha*p + beta
}

# Synthetic data
p <- seq(60,200)
d <- linear(p, alpha = -1.5, beta = 300) + rnorm(sd = 5, length(p))
c <- 88
profit <- d*(p-c)

# Fit of the demand model
lm_model <- lm(d~p)
profit_fitted <-  lm_model$fitted.values*(p - c)

# Pricing Optimization
alpha <- lm_model$coefficients[2]
beta <- lm_model$coefficients[1]
p_max_profit <- (alpha*c - beta)/(2*alpha)

# Plots: Prices X Demand 
df_linear <- data.table('Prices' = p, 'Demand' = d,
                       'profit_fitted' = profit_fitted, 'Profit' = profit)

ggplot(df_linear) + aes(x = Prices, y = Demand) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm)

# Plots: Prices X Profit
ggplot(df_linear) + 
  aes(x = Prices, y = Profit) +
  geom_point() + geom_vline(xintercept = p_max_profit, lty = 2) +
  geom_line(data = df_linear, aes(x = Prices, y = profit_fitted), color = 'blue')
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to obtain one specific point? I believe the graph is plotting maximum profit for every  price point